# Am I the receiver or sender?

Tags: grammar, tense, usage

My friend recently recieved an email about a warning of an attachment might contain virus because of being an executable file. The email is like this;

> xxx@gmail.com is sent an email contains "Executable Files".

Does this mean, the original email was sent from my email or Am I the receiver? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you sure it writes *is*? Isn't it *has*?

Comment: Strictly grammatically, xxx@gmail.com is the receiver of said email. However, the grammar of the whole sentence is so terrible that I would not dare to guess what was meant exactly.

Comment: I agree with oerkelens. *An email contains* sounds wrong; I think it should be *an email containing*.

Comment: Can you make sure that what you have in the blockquote is exactly what the email said?

Comment: If that's literally what the message says, I'd question whether it's a scam message.  A common tactic is create a fake warning to get someone to do something.  Legitimate messages typically use correct grammar.  Scams originating in places where English is not the primary language often contain English mistakes.

Answer (score -1):

> xxx@gmail.com **is sent** an email contains "Executable Files".

it means that *xxx@gmail.com* has been sent a questionable email, is *xxx@gmail.com* your address or someone else's?